# Can i make different templates of displayName in AD? Windows Server 2022

Tags: active-directory, users, windows-server-2022

First of all, sorry for my lack of english.

I need to know if I can create different templates of displayName. Recently, I discovered the ADSI Edit utility and helped me to modify the displayName when I create a new user.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you hint at the createDialog (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-createdialog) attribute here? Exactly this is how the name will be set in the user creation dialog. That dialog does not have an option for multiple templates. However, you could consider custom tools such as a Powershell script that asks for the same things and then creates the user account